# Both ESLint and TypeScript report duplicate warnings in VSCode

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, eslint

I setup a new React TypeScript project, and then installed ESLint using the config prompt. I specified that my project uses React and TypeScript.

For some style warnings, I get duplicate warnings from both TypeScript and ESLint. How can I make it so that TypeScript and ESLint warnings don't overlap? Do I have to manually remove some rules from ESLint or is there a pre-made .eslintrc config file to solve this?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could silence the ESLint warning by disabling the rule in your `.eslintrc.js` (or `.eslintrc.json`, etc.) like this:

```
..
rules: {
  'no-unused-vars': 'off',
  '@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars': 'off',
  ..
}
..
```

However, I personally prefer to disable the TypeScript warning, since the ESLint rule is a bit more configurable. To disable it in TypeScript, set these compiler options in your `tsconfig.json`:

```
..
"compilerOptions": {
  "noUnusedLocals": false,
  "noUnusedParameters": false,
  ..
}
..
```

Now you can for example tweak the ESLint rule to not trigger on identifiers that start with a `_`, by including this in your `.eslintrc.js`:

```
..
rules: {
  'no-unused-vars': 'off',
  '@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars':
    ['warn', {argsIgnorePattern: '^_', varsIgnorePattern: '^_'}],
  ..
}
```

Note that the base rule `no-unused-vars` is recommended to always be disabled by the [`@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars` docs](https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/no-unused-vars/). For an overview of all the options of `@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars`, check the [`no-unused-vars` docs](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-vars), since the options are the same.